How to check if no activity on keyboard and mouse in C++
I'm trying to make an app for myself and others in windows (linux and mac in future) that tracks how much you have worked or did some other activity for a period of time, for example: studied, entertained etc., and one of the features of this app is whenever there is no activity on keyboard or mouse for a set amount of time (lets say 2 minutes) the timer stops, and declares you as AFK, however, if you do press the keyboard or move the mouse before the timer has stopped, then the AFK timer restarts. So basically, whenever a key is pressed system-wide in your pc or mouse has moved, the AFK timer starts counting and when it hits 2 minutes the main timer stops so as to not count you still working because actually you were afk.
So in order to achieve the keyboard part, I'm thinking of using windows hooks but I've heard they are not good for cpu usage but if you make it a dll then it won't be bad for cpu usage right? and to check if the mouse has moved I'm thinking of doing this every 5 seconds:
POINT p;
    if (GetCursorPos(&p))
    {
        // restart timer if mouse pos different from 5 seconds ago
    }

So I just want to know if I should use hooks for the keyboard and the GetCursorPos for mouse, and I want a solution which should not take too much cpu usage because the app has to stay 24/7 in the tray and only show window when you want to see the statistics of your time working in bar charts and pie graphs

C++ itself doesn't have any concept of "mouse" or "keyboard", but the operating system does. So what operating system are you targeting?

windows as i said in the beginning

"windows" is a plural of "window". If you mean OS name, then it's at least "Windows" or better "MS Windows".

you can call every 1-2 min GetLastInputInfo and view are was new user input after last call

well I'm sorry for thinking I would confuse anyone right after saying two operating systems after windows  "windows (linux and mac in future)"

In Windows you can create a kernel level driver to intercept keyboard interrupts. That's not difficult, but you better get a book to understand how to write drivers. And you better test it in a virtual machine or you may crash the system.

@RbMm -- According to Microsoft documentation, the GetLastInputInfo function does not provide information about input events from other processes or other users. It only provides the time of the last input event for the current session.

@Gene You're probably misinterpreting what "session" means here. GetLastInputInfo() returns information for the entire interactive desktop, regardless of which process' thread received the input.

@IInspectable -- yes, Windows nonserver editions allow only a single interactive session, but a user may run virtual machines, events from those won't be received.

@Gene I'm fairly sure that input directed at a VM still goes through the host OS' input processing pipeline and thus affects the timestamp returned by GetLastInputInfo().

Note that an auto-clicker app, or simply just putting something wobbly against the mouse, will defeat anything you come up with. Gamers do this all the time when they need to go AFK and don't want their game to timeout.

It's not for workplaces it's for myself and people who want to know how much they've worked shown in cool bar charts and graphs, so doing that would defeat the whole purpose of using this app

@Remy Lebeau -- even easier than that, there are macro recorders that would record mouse/keyboard events and play them back on specified schedule.
